# issue with MYSQL Query join

Tags: php, mysql

i am performing search function i have contactgroup and language,

Here is mysql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contact where isdeleted = 0  ";

      if ($language !="" && $language !="Empty" ){

                $language_exp = explode(',', $language);
     $sql .= " INNER JOIN contactlanguage ON contact.id = contactlanguage.contactid
INNER JOIN language ON contactlanguage.languageid = language.id AND language.language in ('".implode("', '", $language_exp)."')"; 

            }


    if ($contactgroup !="" && $contactgroup !="Empty" ){



    $contactgroup_exp = explode(',', $contactgroup);
    $sql .= " AND contactgroup in ('".implode("', '", $contactgroup_exp)."')";

    }
```

there are three cases first if i select only language the it will perform query like this

its not working

```
SELECT * FROM contact where isdeleted = 0 INNER JOIN contactlanguage ON contact.id = contactlanguage.contactid INNER JOIN language ON contactlanguage.languageid = language.id AND language.language in ('English', '')
```

second if not selected language only selecting contactgroup its working,

```
SELECT * FROM contact where isdeleted = 0 AND contactgroup in ('Contactgroup1', '')
```

third case if i select both language and contactgroup its not working

```
SELECT * FROM contact where isdeleted = 0  INNER JOIN contactlanguage ON contact.id = contactlanguage.contactid INNER JOIN language ON contactlanguage.languageid = language.id AND language.language in ('English', '') AND contactgroup in ('Contactgroup1', '')
```

can anyone guide me how to perform the query for case 1 and case 3,thanks

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN query is wrong and you will need to move the where condition after the JOIN statement something as

```
SELECT * FROM contact 
INNER JOIN contactlanguage ON contact.id = contactlanguage.contactid
INNER JOIN language ON contactlanguage.languageid = language.id
where 
isdeleted = 0   
AND language.language in ('English', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

The query's are wrong. You must first add the `join` statement and thene then `where`

`SELECT * FROM contact INNER JOIN contactlanguage ON contact.id = ... where isdeleted = 0`